# Why this canvas drawing is causing memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, html5-canvas

The following code is causing a memory/CPU leak - CPU usage quickly increases and reaches 100% in a few minutes, which is detrimental to performance. I want to understand why is this happening so I won't make similar mistakes in the future.

```
function drawBoard(w, h, p, context) {

  for (var x = 0; x <= w; x += 40) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, h + p);
  }


  for (var x = 0; x <= h; x += 40) {
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
    context.lineTo(w + p, 0.5 + x + p);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();

}
let cancel
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let context = ctx
function Loop() {
  cancel = window.requestAnimationFrame(Loop)
  drawBoard(800, 600, 10, context)
}
Loop()
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem. Can you provide more information about how to replicate it? I recommend using `context.beginPath()` at the beginning of your draw function nonetheless.

Comment: @Sphinx that's the normal behavior of `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this bug with just the provided code and a canvas in both Chrome and Firefox. In both browsers the FPS gradually drops while CPU usage increases. In Chrome FPS drops to 40, in Firefox to 17 and even lower. Firefox debugger reports high self times for functions Graphics and drawBoard.

Update: adding context.beginPath() at the begging of drawBoard() seem to have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are never using context.beginPath();

This is from MDN: "The CanvasRenderingContext2D.beginPath() method of the Canvas 2D API starts a new path **by emptying the list of sub-paths**"

```js
function drawBoard(w, h, p, context) {

  for (var x = 0; x <= w; x += 40) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, h + p);
    context.stroke();
   
  }


  for (var y = 0; y <= h; y += 40) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + y + p);
    context.lineTo(w + p, 0.5 + y + p);
    context.stroke();
  }

}
let cancel
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let w = canvas.width = 800;
let h = canvas.height= 600;
let context = ctx
function Loop() {
  cancel = window.requestAnimationFrame(Loop);
  context.clearRect(0,0,w,h)
  drawBoard(w, h, 10, context)
}
Loop()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```